# Discrepancy in !objsize in hex and decimal

Tags: windbg, sos, sosex

I use **!objsize** command to get the true value of an object. For example when I run the command below, it tells me that size of object at address 00000003a275f218 is 18 hex which translates to 24 in decimal.

```
0:000> !ObjSize 00000003a275f218 
sizeof(00000003a275f218) = 24 (0x18) bytes
```

So far so good. I am running same command on an object and its size seem to have a discrepancy between hex and decimal.
[image]

So the size in hex is 0xafbde200. When I convert it to decimal using my calc, this comes to be **2948456960** whereas the output of command is showing decimal size to be **-1346510336**. Can someone help me understand why there is difference in sizes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in SOS. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/ToolBox/SOS/Strike/strike.cpp), you'll find the method declared as

```
DECLARE_API(ObjSize)
```

It uses the following format as output

```
ExtOut("sizeof(%p) = %d (0x%x) bytes (%S)\n", SOS_PTR(obj), size, size, methodTable.GetName());
```

As you can see it uses `%d` as the format specifier, which is for signed decimal integers. That should be `%u` for unsigned decimal integers instead, since obviously you can't have objects using negative amount of memory.

If you know how to use Git, you may provide a patch.

You can use `?` in WinDbg to see the unsigned value:

```
0:000> ? 0xafbde200
Evaluate expression: 2948456960 = 00000000`afbde200
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for taking the time to check the source!

Answer (score 2):

Difference is the sign. It seems to be interpreting the first bit (which is 1 since the first hex byte is "A") as a negative sign. These two numbers are otherwise the same.

Paste -1346510336 on calc.exe (programmer mode), switch to Hex:

FFFFFFFFAFBDE200

Paste 2948456960, switch to Hex:

AFBDE200

Comment: so what is true size of this object. Should I trust value in hex or in decimal?

Comment: I would take the positive value, I see no reason for an objsize function to really mean negative

Comment: you mean you will take +1346510336  as size of  object or 2948456960?

Comment: 2948456960. That's the value if you consider 0XAFBDE200 as an unsigned value.

Comment: so could this be a bug in !ObjSize command where its showing incorrect value in decimal?